# Kubectl command throwing error: Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: exit status 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am doing a lab setup of EKS/Kubectl and after the completion cluster build, I run the following:

```
> kubectl get node

And I get the following error:
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: exit status 2
```

Moreover, I am sure it is a configuration issue for,

```
kubectl version
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

create-cluster                           | delete-cluster                          
describe-cluster                         | describe-update                         
list-clusters                            | list-updates                            
update-cluster-config                    | update-cluster-version                  
update-kubeconfig                        | wait                                    
help                                    
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.1", GitCommit:"d224476cd0730baca2b6e357d144171ed74192d6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-14T21:04:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: exit status 2
```

Please advise next steps for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check your ~/.kube/config file?

Assume if you have start local cluster using minikube for that if your config is available, you should not be getting the error for server.

### Sample config file

```
    apiVersion: v1
    clusters:
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority: /Users/singhvi/.minikube/ca.crt
        server: https://127.0.0.1:32772
      name: minikube
    contexts:
    - context:
        cluster: minikube
        user: minikube
      name: minikube
    current-context: minikube
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
    users:
    - name: minikube
      user:
        client-certificate: /Users/singhvi/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
        client-key: /Users/singhvi/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

Answer (score 8):

Please delete the cache folder folder present in

**~/.aws/cli/cache**

Answer (score 3):

For me running **kubectl get nodes** or **kubectl cluster-info** gives me the following error.

```
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
```

[image: kubectl get nodes giving error]

I did the following to resolve this.

1. Deleted all of the contents inside `~/.kube/`. In my case, its a windows machine, so its C:\Users\nis.kube. Here nis is the user name that I logged into.
2. Ran the get credentials command as follows.

```
    az aks get-credentials --resource-group terraform-aks-dev --name terraform-aks-dev-aks-cluster --admin
```

Note `--admin` in the end. Without it, its giving me the same error.

Now the above two commands are working.

Reference: https://blog.baeke.info/2021/06/03/a-quick-look-at-azure-kubelogin/

Comment: It's bad practice to use admin credentials and in a proper configured AKS cluster with disabled local accounts, the --admin parameter will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have the kubectl configuration file ready?

Normally we put it under `~/.kube/config` and the file includes the cluster endpoint, ceritifcate, contexts, admin users, and so on.

Furtherly, read this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html

Comment: On the money!  Thank you for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, as I am using azure (not aws), I had to [install "kubelogin"](https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin) which resolved the issue.

"kubelogin" is a client-go credential (exec) plugin implementing azure authentication. This plugin provides features that are not available in kubectl. It is supported on kubectl v1.11+

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed AWS CLI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to update/recreate your local kubeconfig. In my case I deleted the whole `~/.kube/config` and followed this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the issue was that in my .aws/credentials file there was multiple users, and the user that had the permissions on the cluster of EKS (admin_test) wasn't the default user. So in my case, i made the "admin_test" user as my default user in the CLI using environment variables:

```
export $AWS_PROFILE='admin_test'
```

After that, i checked the default user with the command:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Finally, i was able to get the nodes with the *kubectl get nodes* command.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

In EKS you can retrieve your kubectl credentials using the following command:

```
% aws eks update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name
Updated context arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:xxx:cluster/cluster_name in /Users/theofpa/.kube/config
```

You can retrieve your cluster name using:

```
% aws eks list-clusters
{
    "clusters": [
        "cluster_name"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by upgrading my awscli to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure:

1. Delete all contents of the ~/.kube/ folder
2. Execute:

   sudo az aks install-cli

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1106601/aks-access-issue)

3. Reconnect:

   az login

   az aks get-credentials -n {clustername} -g {resourcegroup}

It worked for me for Azure.

Answer (score -8):

Removing and adding the `~/.aws/credentials` file worked to resolve this issue for me.

```
rm ~/.aws/credentials
touch ~/.aws/credentials
```