# Is it possible to deploy an existing container via EKS using AWS Console only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks

So I created my first ever EKS Cluster (this URL is for illustration only):

`https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/eks/home?region=us-east-1#/clusters/MyEksClusterName?selectedTab=cluster-overview-tab`

and I would like to use it to practice `Docker` container deployment via EKS.

I looked for step by step instructions on how to accomplish that using AWS Console operations only (i.e. no `kubctl`, no `aws` CLI) but all the instructions that I have been able to find involve some necessary CLI interaction. For example:

https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetes-application-deployment-with-aws-eks-and-ecr-4600e11b2d3c

I did manage to [create a kubeconfig file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html) (including `role-arn`) and

```
set KUBECONFIG=C:\Users\Me\mydockercontainer\kubeconfig
```

but when I tried to run `kubectl get componentstatuses`, I received:

```
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.
```

I am not using anything related to `Go` in my environment... I researched this error message and found: [*"Make sure you have installed AWS CLI.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73701969/3154666)

I therefore went ahead and installed AWS CLI:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.11.22 Python/3.11.3 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

but when I tried now to run `kubectl get componentstatuses`, I received:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 253
```

I did find instructions on `aws configure`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

but at this point, I feel that I overcomplicated things and that I have been delving too deep into a procedure that would have been much simpler. That is, compared to just point and click various options on AWS Console (just like when creating an IAM role, user, EC2 instance, etc.).

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to deploy an existing container via EKS using **AWS Console only**?
2. Where can I find step by step instructions on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. You need to know more about `how kubernetes and iam roles works, rather how EKS works`. EKS is just a way to have your own K8s cluster with all its needed underlying infrastructure (Network, storage, computing, ect) on the Cloud. And the console page you see for EKS, is just a UI to check your resources deployed and the cluster information as api endpoint.

The entry point for any K8s cluster (regardless locally, on AWS/Azure/GCP/ect), is the api server, which is an actual endpoint (on eks you would find in the `overview` tab, under `API server endpoint` parameter) that you reach and you can perform any API request. **In order to do so, you need to be authenticated and authorized.**

In AWS EKS, the cluster authenticate based on IAM role. So in the [link you provided for the kubeconfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html#:%7E:text=%2D%20%2D%2Dregion%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20%24region_code%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20eks%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20get%2Dtoken%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20%2D%2Dcluster%2Dname%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20%24cluster_name:%7E:text=args%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20%2D%2Dregion%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20%24region_code%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20eks%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20get%2Dtoken%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20%2D%2Dcluster%2Dname%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20%24cluster_name), in the `users` definition, kubectl authenticate by running `aws eks get-token`. And in order to be able to run this command, you need to have right permissions attached to **the aws profile that is used in your shell** to run the previous command. Please refer to [How to configure aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

After you configure your aws profile in your shell, run the `aws eks get-token --cluster-name <<name>> --region <<region>>` manually, and see if it works. If it does, then kubectl will work as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance. As an AWS newbie, I wasn't sure whether I was spending the time in the right direction... Your answer really helps.

Comment: And so, after running `aws configure` (without `sso`! because I only created a service IAM role, not SSO or "IAM Identity Center") I am now getting the same exact problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56863539/3154666 Looks like I am making progress. :)